# Flowplayer loading bar not going away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flowplayer

I've been working on a video uploading script, you can upload a video (I haven't tested all video formats yet) and it'll convert the video to .mp4, .ogg, and .webm files.

I'm using flowplayer to embed the video, and you [can see a test video working](http://dev.wackywalr.us/videos/view.php?id=2), but the loading bar doesn't go away so you can't get to the controls. Here's my embed code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=$url;?>javascript/flowplayer/skin/minimalist.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=$url;?>javascript/flowplayer/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
```

(I don't think that part is the problem)

and

```
<div class="flowplayer" data-swf="<?=$url;?>javscript/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.417">
      <video autoplay>
         <source type="video/webm" src="<?=$video->file('webm');?>" />
         <source type="video/mp4" src="<?=$video->file('mp4');?>" />
         <source type="video/ogg" src="<?=$video->file('ogg');?>" />
      </video>
    </div>
```

I've tried removing the data-swf and the data-ratio attributes, I've tried moving around the link and script tags, but no cigar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I'll put it here in case anyone gets the same problem.

It might have to do with using the newest jQuery version from Google's hosted library, but flowplayer.js had this:

```
on("mouseout.tip", function()
```

When they should have used

```
bind("mouseout.tip", function()
```

Comment: jQuery 1.7 and onwards supports .on(), and I think it's favoured from that point on. I've certainly got into the habit of using it instead of bind() or click() etc!  
I use jQuery 1.8.3 with no problems.